# When using gwt-log source maps doesn't work when catching uncaught exceptions

Tags: java, gwt, logging, gwtp, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have recently started using [gwt-log](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/).

I followed the Getting Started tutorial and added `Log.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` in my initialization file as suggested, but when it is there I get this exception in the chrome console (using super dev mode):

```
2014-07-31 15:16:21,025 [FATAL] Uncaught Exception:
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError)
 __gwt$exception: <skipped>: Cannot read property 'formatTotal' of null
    at Unknown.$getTotal_1(project-0.js@33:126146)
    at Unknown.$getFromModel_198(project-0.js@65:103988)
    at Unknown.getFromModel_199(project-0.js@10:104011)
    at Unknown.$visit(project-0.js@15:22142)
    at Unknown.visit_3(project-0.js@10:22188)
    at Unknown.$traverse(project-0.js@11:21813)
    at Unknown.accept_73(project-0.js@33:103339)
    at Unknown.$traverse(project-0.js@57:21813)
    at Unknown.$traverse_0(project-0.js@13:21877)
    at Unknown.attach(project-0.js@21:21903)
    ...
```

Quite hard to debug as you can see, no line numbers or link to java source. When I comment out the `Log.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` line I get the source mapped to the exception like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatTotal' of null UnitRate.java:87
$getTotal_1 UnitRate.java:87
$getFromModel_198 UnitRateRenderer_total_Context.java:17
getFromModel_199 UnitRateRenderer_total_Context.java:16
$visit Refresher.java:30
visit_3 Initializer.java:49
$traverse AbstractEditorContext.java:128
accept_73 UnitRateRenderer_SimpleBeanEditorDelegate.java:57
$traverse AbstractEditorContext.java:129
$traverse_0 AbstractEditorDelegate.java:100
...
```

**Is this expected behaviour or am I not doing something I should be?**

Comment: what is at line `UnitRate.java:87`?

Comment: I know what the error is. formatTotal belongs to a class that is null, as this instance hasn't been instantiated by guice. That's not the problem though, it's about the logging framework.